# Generating tuples modulo index

Tags: algorithm, tuples, combinatorics

I am looking for an algorithm (or a C-like implementation, no itertools available) which generates all tuples
[a_0 a_1 ... a_(n-1)] such that 0 <= a_i <= i + 1. Pointers to literature are also welcome.

Comment: Are there any other limitations on a_i? for example a_i >=0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
void printTuples (int n, int[] a, int i=0) {
    if (i == n) {
        //print a
        return;
    }
    for (int j=0; j<=i+1; j++) {
        a[i] = j;
        printTuples (n, a, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need j<=i+1 probably in loop condition.

Comment: In this solution a[0] <= 0 but should be <= 1. Thanks anyway, was pretty fast!

Comment: I accept the answer because it helped me. Thank you! However the solution is not correct. Your function gives (for n=3) 000,001,002,010,011,012.

Comment: @John did you try it after the fix?

Comment: tried mine now, it gives 000,001,002,003,010,011,012,013,020,021,022,023,100,101,102,103,110,111,112,113,120,121,122,123

Answer (score 0):

It's called backtracking. Search wikipedia about it. You can do it both recursive or iterative.

Amir, he wants between 0 and i + 1, not between 0 and i. And i think passing arrays on the stack is slower thant accesing them as global.

I think you want something like this:

```
int a[YOUR_LENGTH];

void backtracking (int n, int counter) {
    if (counter == n) {
        // do whatever
        return;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= counter + 1; ++ j) {
        a[counter] = j;
        backtracking(n, counter + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the <= problem and arrays are passed as pointers. any way, I don't know on what language and platform he will use, so it's not really relevant.

Comment: Usually it's better to avoid globals. It's backtracking, the couple milliseconds you might win by using a global are definitely not worth it.

Comment: Teodor, you forgot to replace the 'i' from Amir's solution by 'counter', no? Thanks for the information on 'backtracking'.

Comment: Hmm, I am a pain in the neck, I know, but there is still an 'i'. ... and a missing '}'. But I will give you a point when I am above the 15 point limit imposed by SO.